# Pyqtgraph TextItem center align text

Tags: html, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I am trying to use pyqtgraph to make text center aligned rather than left aligned using html. However it seems that when I use `<div style="text-align: center"></div>` it doesn't seem to have an effect.

```py
import sys
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

win = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
gv = pg.GraphicsView()
win.setCentralWidget(gv)
win.show()

text = pg.TextItem(html='<div style="text-align: center">I am on the top<br>bottom</div>',
                  fill=QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
text.setPos(100, 100)
gv.addItem(text)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Gives

[image: this]

The bottom text is not center aligned at all, and when I change `<div style="text-align: center"></div>` to `<div style="text-align: right"></div>` for example, it still doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the text alignment you can use the document() of the internal QGraphicsTextItem:

```
text = pg.TextItem(html='<div>I am on the top<br>bottom</div>',
                  fill=QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))

it = text.textItem
option = it.document().defaultTextOption()
option.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
it.document().setDefaultTextOption(option)
it.setTextWidth(it.boundingRect().width())

text.setPos(100, 100)
gv.addItem(text)
```

[image]